# Find the maximum possible $k$ s.t. $\langle v_i,v_j\rangle\leq 0$ for all $i\neq j$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k$ are non-zero vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\langle v_i,v_j\rangle\leq 0$ for all $i\neq j$. The question is to find the maximum possible $k$.

Comment: My guess: $k=2n-1$

Comment: At least $k$ is 2n, as you can consider $\{\pm e_i: 1\leq i\leq n\}$.